# Is there a way to back up/restore SharePoint 2010 Application Pages built with Visual Studio?

Tags: sharepoint-server, backup, restore, visual-studio-2012, application-pages

I have a few separate Application Pages built for SharePoint 2010 using Visual Studio 2012 and I'd like a way to back up and restore these SharePoint solutions (does not have to be a SharePoint based backup/restore) in case of server failure or other means.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to be able to create an `Application Page` in SharePoint, you should create a SharePoint Solution then add an application page that must be deployed as farm solution only.

When you build your solution, it's packaged in a SharePoint Solution package (WSP) file. and you can use PowerShell `Add-SPSolution` and `Install-SPSolution` to deploy it to your farm.

After deploying your solution the Application page will be located in 14 hive at `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\yoursolution name`

And the WSP solution should be listed in `Central administration > System Management > Manage Farm Solutions`

**So you need to backup and restore a WSP solution rather than page as the following:**

**Backup WSP solution,**

Now you will be able to backup all the WSP solution that deployed to your farm via PowerShell as the following:

```
$FolderPath = "c:\WSPSolutions"  
foreach ($solution in Get-SPSolution)  
{  
   $id = $Solution.SolutionID  
   $title = $Solution.Name  
   $filename = $Solution.SolutionFile.Name  
   $solution.SolutionFile.SaveAs("$FolderPath\$filename") 
}
```

Or you can just backup specific solution as

```
$file = (Get-SPFarm).Solutions.Item("AppPageSolution.wsp").SolutionFile
$file.SaveAs("c:\backup\AppPageSolution.wsp")
```

**Restore WSP solution,**

- you can perform bulk deploy using https://spsd.codeplex.com/
- Or use `Add-SPSolution` and `Install-SPSolution`.

For more details check [Install and deploy a SharePoint (WSP) Solution Package using SharePoint Shell](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/20/how-to-deploy-a-sharepoint-wsp-solution-package/)